# How does Shelyn feel about Philters of Love, according to the lore?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, lore, religions-and-deities, golarion

One of my players off-handedly mentioned the possibility of acquiring a [Philter of Love](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/m-p/philter-of-love/), which has the following description:

> **Philter of Love**
>
> This potent preparation causes a creature who drinks it to fall madly in love with the first creature he or she perceives after consuming it. The drinker’s attitude toward that creature becomes helpful. If a romantic attraction is possible toward the first person viewed, the drinker falls in love with that person. Otherwise, the drinker’s love is a platonic adoration. The effects of the philter are permanent unless removed by a *break enchantment*, *dispel magic*, *limited wish*, *miracle*, *remove curse*, or *wish*.

Another player is a cleric of Shelyn, the goddess of art, beauty, love, and music. In the unlikely event that the PCs follow up on the idea of getting a Philter of Love, would Shelyn be displeased if her cleric went along with it?

[Some sources](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Shelyn) describe her as the goddess of love "in all its forms", which sort of suggests that she might be okay with it. On the other hand, the fact that a Philter of Love can be undone by magic (and [Remove Curse](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/remove-curse/) at that) makes me think that it doesn't count as "real love" as far as Shelyn is concerned.

Are there any sources that show Shelyn having feelings one way or another about relationships built on magical influence, such as Philters of Love, *charm person*, etc.? How she feels about relationships built on dishonesty (e.g., a poor street rat claiming to be a noble to woo a princess) might also be relevant.

Comment: I hoping that someone might know of a source that would provide more information. Not necessarily something specifically about a Philter of Love - maybe a scenario or other story involving *charm person* or an obsessive lover looking for a way to make the target of his affections love him back.

Comment: @Ifusaso If I may, the asker seems to be looking for evidence from the game's material or from informed experts that supports or discourages a creature's actions in light of the creature's faith. If no evidence exists—even obliquely or by extension—, that should be an answer. Instead of putting the question on hold, maybe unsupported, pure-opinion-based answers should be downvoted? (That question's literal not rhetorical, by the way; I could be totally off-base. (It's happened!) However, the asker should edit the question so that it's absolutely clear what kind of evidence is acceptable.)

Comment: I think Hey I Can Chan covered it pretty well. I've edited the question to try and clarify what sort of answers I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

**She's just fine with it.**

Shelyn has as part of her domains, the domain of Charm (per Faiths of Purity). [Charm includes](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo-domains/charm-domain/) a whole bunch of enchantment/compulsion magic. Furthermore, all three subdomains of the Charm domain include enchantment/compulsion magic of some form. So while she *is* Neutral Good, consent doesn't seem to be high on her priority list. Because of this, I infer that enchantment/compulsion magic via potion would have similar, if not the same rules.

Comment: Just because a boss can provide a workman with tools that could enable the workman to commit murder doesn't mean the boss *approves* of murder. `:-)` I think there's a little room for nuance here.

Comment: @HeyICanChan You are absolutely correct, but the question does not discuss the details on how the Philter would be administered, just whether it could without offending Shelyn. Considering enchantment is, by its nature, bending consent, I would argue it's the exact same *sort* of tool as the Philter.